# Deadlock in interrupt context

Tags: linux, kernel, deadlock, interrupt

Interrupt context have higher priority than other context in the system and their execution should be fast and reliable. Imagine that a spinlock is held by some process in kernel mode and while it is held by it, an interrupt occurs. The interrupt context will preemt the other process while he still holds the lock. If the interrupt context needs the same lock, it might be spinning on it forever and hence causing a deadlock.

What would be the effect on the entire system in such case, will it hang?

Comment: "What would be the effect on the entire system in such case, will it hang?" - Yes, with deadlock'ed spinlocks the entire system could hang. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.